# Time complexity recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I need to find the recurrence relation:

```
int search(int[] a, int l, int h, int goal) { 
    if (low == high) return 0; 
    int tg = target(a, l, h); 
    if (goal < target) 
        return search(a, l, tg-1, goal); 
    else if (goal > target) 
        return search(a, tg +1, h, goal); 
    else 
        return a[tg];
}
```

What would be the initial way to approach this question? I'm not asking for a solution, but just an initial way to approach it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not asking about an exact solution (however, I can provide that if you want), I'm going to give you a hint, which is a very simple, yet not a well-known method of approaching such problems.

The crucial idea is to modify your function to a function which has probably worst complexity, but its **expected** complexity can be measured easily, let's call this modified function `findTarget2`:

```
public static int findTarget2 (int[] a, int low, int high, int goal) { 
    if (low == high) return 0;
    int len = high - low + 1; //length of the array range, i.e. input size
    while (true) { 
       int target = selectTarget(a, low, high); 
       if (goal < target && target-low <= 3/4 * len) 
          return findTarget2(a, low, target-1, goal); 
       else if (goal > target && high-target <= 3/4 * len) 
          return findTarget2(a, target+1, high, goal); 
       else if (goal == target)
          return a[target];
    }

}
```

Now, let `f(n)` be the time complexity of the original, and `g(n)` be the time complexity of the `findTarget2` function, where `n` is the size of their input, i.e. the length of the array range equal `high-low+1`.

Now, let's say that `selectTarget` results in a **bad execution** if and only if it doesn't cause any return call inside the while's body.

The first observation is that `g(n) >= f(n)`, because in a case of a bad execution, `findTarget2` basically calls itself on the same input, while the original function reduces the size of input by at least 1. Thus, if have an upper bound for `g(n)`, then the same bound applies to `f(n)`.

Next, the expected time complexity of `g(n)` can be written as follows:

```
EX[g(n)] <= EX[g(3/4 * n) + X * O(n)]
```

which can be written as follows using linearity of expected value:

```
EX[g(n)] <= EX[g(3/4 * n)] + EX[X] * O(n)
```

where `X` is the random variable denoting the number of while loop executions until it results in return call, and the last `O(n)` is the non-recursive time spent in `findTarget2` function, and it's `O(n)`, because it is said that `selectTarget` function runs in that time.

Now your task is just to compute `EX[X]` and then you can use [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to get the final expected time complexity of `g(n)`, which is also an upper bound for the expected time complexity of `f(n)`, so the upper bound of the complexity of the original function.

Comment: Thank's. One question: selectTarget() what does exactly do? Is it like a random value between the specified range?

Comment: @Wazowski you defined what it does: "A non-recursive method selectTarget() has linear time complexity T(n) = c · n where n = high − low + 1 and returns integer target in the range low ≤ target ≤ high. Output values of selectTarget() are distributed uniformly in this range. Thus if low = 0 and high = n − 1, then every target = 0, 1,..., n − 1 occurs with the same probability 1/n ." It's important that it returns each value with the same probability.

Comment: I know, but I don't get what it returns, a random integer between the range?

Comment: Yes, as you wrote: "returns integer target in the range low ≤ target ≤ high", so it returns integer in the range [low, high], each possible one with equal probability.

Comment: Another two questions: from where does 2/3 come? And what does Exp[] mean? Exponential?

Comment: It has been you choice?

Comment: Okay thank you so much.  What would be the recurrence relation?